# Pandas dataframe total making it into each smaller frame and then concatenating in the end

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

dfTotal:

```
     keyword  variation_percentage    date
0    Ansiedade                   NaN  2016-01-01
1    Ansiedade            135.222672  2016-01-02
2    Ansiedade             -5.163511  2016-01-03
3    Ansiedade             -1.149425  2016-01-04
4    Ansiedade              4.100367  2016-01-05
..         ...                   ...         ...
295      Preco              2.346403  2016-02-25
296      Preco              6.425339  2016-02-26
297      Preco             33.333333  2016-02-27
298      Preco              2.040816  2016-02-28
299      Preco            -40.625000  2016-02-29
```

The column keyword repeats multiple times. The column for the date also repeats relative to the keyword. For example, the date will be unique up to the point where the keyword in the DF changes, then it repeats exactly the same.

I want to split this dataframe so that it becomes the date in the first column (the range only once so that it doesnt repeat itself). This means that the date range for one keyword is the same for all of the keywords. So we need  all of the next columns concated together so that they show keyword_VAR, keyword2_VAR so here it would be ansiedade_VAR with the variation values then keyword2_VAR with its variation values...etc.

so

```
        date  ansiedade_VAR  Preço_Var  ... keyword_VAR
  2016-01-01  NaN             ....           ....
  2016-01-02  135.222672
  2016-01-03  -5.163511
  2016-01-04  -1.149425 
  2016-01-05   4.10036
  ...           ...                   ...         ...
  2016-02-25
  2016-02-26
  2016-02-27
  2016-02-28
  2016-02-29
```

All of the data is in the DFTotal.

I started running this loop for the date but it did not work:

```
for i in dfKeyword['keyword']:
    for j in dfTotal['keyword']:
        if i == j:
            newDf = pd.DataFrame
            newDf['date'][j] = dfTotal['date'][j]
            break
```

I would have replicated this loop for the keywords and inserted a variable in the string. I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runQuery.py", line 35, in <module>
    newDf['date'][j] = dfTotal['date'][j]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Ansiedade'
```

I need help with this. Thanks so much in advance, let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is exactly what you want, but I believe this should work.

```
df.set_index(['date','keyword']).unstack().reset_index().add_suffix('_var').droplevel(0,axis=1).rename(columns = {'_var':'date'}).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Comment: I need another dataframe to become just a column for the date and the other columns the keyword_VAR in short.

You think you can help?

Comment: Does the code above solve the issue? Do you just need to separate the output into two dataframes?